# visio referencing to other pages within same document

Tags: visio

I'm running into a tedious issue.

I have a VISIO workbook that contains at least 100 pages, my issue is that I have a textbox that makes reference to multiple pages. EXAMPLE: on page 10, I have a textbox that that says: "SEE PAGE 45". The problem is that my document changes page count throughout a project quite often. Therefore, if I add another page before page 45, well its not page 45 anymore, it is page 46, hence, now I have to go back to page 10 and other pages that make reference to page 45 and change the text to page 46!

This is very nerve wrecking! I tried using "User-defined Cells" with ="SEE PAGE "&PAGENUMBER() but that gives you the page number of current page that the shape is located on. Not what I want....

NUTSHELL:
I want page 10's textbox referencing page 45 and if page 45's location changes (i.e. changes to page 46 or 50 or etc) I want that text (on page 10) to update to page 45's new location automatically.

Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Please check [same thread](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&nv=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://visio.getbb.ru/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D5%26t%3D1398&xid=17259,15700022,15700186,15700191,15700248,15700253&usg=ALkJrhiJuJj3TWlbI6JT_BcSkemDhA450Q) in Russian visio forum (via google translate service)